# Taking the limit of an integral using residues, why is this wrong?

Tags: limits, infinity, residue-calculus

I have the integral $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+a^2} dx$ where $a$ is a positive real number. The strategy was to evaluate the limit of the integral on the boundary of a half-disk of radius $R$ and then subtract the limit of the integral on the half-circle.

What I am confused with, is that when computing the integral on the boundary of the half-disk, I used the residue theorem to compute the integral thinking that $\cos(x)$ is meromorphic everywhere but infinity, and our domain is a finite (open) disk, and then took the limit.  However, the reference I am using, says that $\cos(x)$ has an essential singularity at infinity and thus uses a different strategy (computing the limit for $\frac{\exp(ix)}{x^2+a^2}$ and then taking the real part). I don't understand why I cannot use the residue theorem, and then take the limit in this case, because our domain (although gets unbounded when taking a limit) is a finite disk on which cosine is meromorphic.

Can someone please explain where I am going wrong in my thinking?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use Eulers formula to rewrite the denominator. The sine is an odd function, so don't worry about that. x²+a² is factorable (x+ai)(x-ai) and there is a pole at x=ai which you plug in. (Now which linar term from the denominator "disappears" for Cauchy' formula??)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very hard to "control" or check how the module of the complex sine or cosine are going to behave. This is one reason why we usually use $\,e^{ix}\,$  instead. So define

$$f(z):=\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+a^2}\;,\;\;C_R:=[-R,R]\cup\,\left(\gamma_R:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;z=Re^{it}\;,\;0<t<\pi\}\,\right)\;,\;\;0<a<R$$

The only singularity of the above function within the domain enclosed by the above path is at the simple pole

$$z=ai\;\implies\;\;\text{Res}_{z=ai}(f)=\lim_{z\to ai} (z-ai)f(z)\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\frac{e^{-a}}{2ai}$$

So by CRT we get

$$\frac{\pi e^{-a}}a=\oint\limits_{C_R}f(z)\,dz=\int\limits_{-R}^R\frac{e^{ix}}{x^2+a^2}dz+\int\limits_{\gamma_R}f(z)\,dz$$

But either using [Jordan's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma) or directly by the Estimmation Lemma, we get

$$\left|\,\int\limits_{\gamma_R}f(z)\,dz\,\right|\le \frac{e^{-\text{Im}\,{z}}}{R^2-a^2}\pi R\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}0$$

So we finally get

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int\limits_{C_R}f(z)\,dz=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos x+i\sin x}{x^2+a^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{ae^a}$$

and comparing real parts we get our integral.

Comment: Does $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{\gamma_R} \frac{\cos z}{a^{2}+z^{2}} \ dz$ blow up, or does it just not go to zero? I want to say that it can't blow up since the sum of the residues inside of $C_{R}$ is finite. But that might be irrelevant due to the essential singularity at infinity.

Comment: Well, this is part of my problem with those complex trigonometric functions: I really don't know what the limit is off the top of my head, and it perhaps would involve some rather lengthy/nasty computations (with power series...?) to actually find out what goes on there. One thing seems pretty likely: that in the limit and over that half disk the integral vanishes, but again: I can't prove it right now.

Comment: Knowing that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x^2+a^{2}} \ dx = \frac{\pi}{ae^{a}}$ and $\text{Res} \Big[\frac{\cos x}{x^2+a^{2}}, ia \Big] =  \frac{1}{2ia} \cosh (a)$ , I want to say that $ \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{\gamma_R} \frac{\cos z}{a^{2}+z^{2}} \ dz = 2 \pi i \Big(\frac{1}{2ia} \cosh (a) \Big) - \frac{\pi}{ae^{a}}$.  But Wolfram Alpha seems to be telling me I'm wrong.

Comment: @RandomVariable If $z = Re^{i\theta}$ on the arc, then cos(z) takes its maximum value at $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$, so at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ the numerator becomes $\cos(iR) = \cosh(R)$. $\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{\cosh(R)}{R^2} = \infty$, so it seems to me that the integrand blows up as R goes to infinity.

Comment: It does seem to blow up. But how can it blow up if the closed contour $C_{R}$ encloses one pole that has a finite residue?

Comment: @RandomVariable My guess is (and maybe someone better at complex analysis than I can clarify) similar to what you state in your first comment: that the function $\frac{\cos z}{z^2+a^{2}}$ can be considered to have a pole at infinity, and that in the limit as R goes to infinity the contour "intersects" this pole, so the residue theorem doesn't apply.  I definitely could be wrong here, though!

Comment: It has an essential singularity (not a pole) at infinity since $\cos (\frac{1}{z})$ has an essential singularity at the origin. But doesn't $e^{iz}$ have an essential singularity at $\infty$ as well? I really wish someone could clarify this.

Comment: Actually, it does appear to be going to what I stated above.  I parametrized the contour and was having  Wolfram Alpha evaluate the integral for large values of $R$ and for different values of $a$.  But I was integrating from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ instead of from $0$ to $\pi$. I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

Watching the proof of this fact on my note seems that the point it's you need to control the module of your function as $|z|$ goes to infinity. Now the point is that the cosine in the complex plain behaves slightly different regarding the module as its real counterpart. In fact the module of the cosine can assume arbitrarily great values:
$$\cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$
using modules and basical disequalities we obtain $$ \frac{1}{2} | |e^{ix}e^{-y}|-|e^{-ix}e^y|| \leq \frac{1}{2} | e^{ix}e^{-y} -(-e^{-ix}e^{y})|$$
and the former member can be great as you want (note the double module)

So you need to do this "trick" to conclude the proof and therefore use the result. Note,that you have to calculate the residue of $f(z)e^{iz}$ with this method.